# Calculating height and evaluating the vicinity of a peak in a multiplicity function for a two-state paramagnet

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have to calculate the height and width of the multiplicity function for a two-state paramagnet. I'm supposed to do this analogously to the method in the text book, which I will try to outline below. The text book uses a lot of approximations: for instance, the first derivation considers a limit of $q\gg N$. Hopefully it's still clear what I'm asking.

---

## ***Calculating the multiplicity of an Einstein solid for the limit $q\gg N$***

First I'll consider the example from the text book for an Einstein solid of $q$ units of energy and $N$ oscillators.

Starting with the exact formula for multiplicity:

$$\Omega\left(N,q\right)=\binom{q+N-1}{q}=\frac{\left(q+N-1\right)!}{q!\left(N-1\right)!}\approx\frac{\left(q+N\right)!}{q!N!}.$$

Taking the natural logarithm and applying Stirling's approximation:

$$\ln\Omega=\ln\left(\frac{\left(q+N\right)!}{q!N!}\right)$$
$$\ln\Omega=\ln\left(q+N\right)!-\ln q!-\ln N!$$
$$\ln\Omega\approx\left(q+N\right)\ln\left(q+N\right)-\left(q+N\right)-\left(q\ln q-q\right)-\left(N\ln N-N\right)$$
$$\ln\Omega=\left(q+N\right)\ln\left(q+N\right)-q\ln q-N\ln N$$

Using $q\gg N$, we can manipulate $\ln\left(q+N\right)$ using a Taylor series of only the first term:

$$\ln\left(q+N\right)=\ln\left[q\left(1+\frac{N}{q}\right)\right]$$
$$\ln\left(q+N\right)=\ln\left(1+\frac{N}{q}\right)$$
$$\ln\left(q+N\right)\approx\ln q+\frac{N}{q}$$

Plugging this result into the previous expression derived through Stirling's approximation, we find:

$$\ln\Omega\approx N\ln\frac{q}{N}+N+\frac{N^2}{q}$$

of which the last term is approximately zero in the limit $q\gg N$, to find a final expression of:

$$\Omega\left(N,q\right)\approx e^{N\ln(q/N)} e^N=\left(\frac{eq}{N}\right)^N$$

This is the example in the text book.

---

## ***Calculating the multiplicity of a two-state paramagnet***

The next step is to apply the same methods to a two-state paramagnet, for which the multiplicity function is given to be:

$$\Omega\left(N_\uparrow\right)=\binom{N}{N_\uparrow}=\frac{N!}{N_\uparrow!N_\downarrow!}.$$

Taking the logarithm on both sides:

$$\ln\Omega=\ln\left(\frac{N!}{\left(N-N_\downarrow\right)!N_\downarrow!}\right)$$
$$\ln\Omega=\ln N! -\ln\left(N-N_\downarrow\right)!-\ln N_\downarrow!$$
$$\ln\Omega=N\ln N - \left(N-N_\downarrow\right)\ln\left(N-N_\downarrow\right)-N_\downarrow\ln N_\downarrow$$

Approximation of the logarithm $\ln\left(N-N_\downarrow\right)$ can be done by using the Taylor expansion about $a=0$:

$$\ln\left(1-x\right) \approx x + \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\dots$$

Manipulating the logarithm like so:

$$\ln\left(N\left(1-\frac{N_\downarrow}{N}\right)\right)=\ln N+\ln\left(1-\frac{N_\downarrow}{N}\right)$$

Allows to set $x=\frac{N_\downarrow}{N}$ (granted $\ln\left(1-x\right)\approx x$) to acquire a final expression (after cancelling some terms) of:

$$\ln\Omega\approx N_\downarrow\ln \frac{N}{N_\downarrow}+N_\downarrow+\frac{N_\downarrow^2}{N}.$$

Which consequently results in an expression for the multiplicity of:

$$\Omega\approx e^{N_\downarrow\ln \left(N/N_\downarrow\right)}e^{N_\downarrow}=\left(\frac{eN}{N_\downarrow}\right)^{N_\downarrow}$$

Similarly, the multiplicity as function of $N_\uparrow$ is:

$$\Omega\approx e^{N_\uparrow\ln \left(N/N_\uparrow\right)}e^{N_\uparrow}=\left(\frac{eN}{N_\uparrow}\right)^{N_\uparrow}$$

(In both cases the limit $q\gg N$ still applies, so as to take $\frac{N_\downarrow^2}{N}$ to be negligible in the final result.)

---

### *Intermezzo: the height of the peak of the multiplicity function for two large Einstein solids*

Furthermore, in the text book example, the height of the peak in the multiplicity function of two large Einstein solids is calculated through:

$$\Omega=\left(\frac{eq_A}{N}\right)^N\left(\frac{eq_B}{N}\right)^N=\left(\frac{e}{N}\right)^{2N}\left(q_Aq_B\right)^N$$

And consequently setting $q_A=q/2$ to find:

$$\Omega_\mathrm{max}=\left(\frac{e}{N}\right)^{2N}\left(\frac{q}{2}\right)^{2N}$$

---

## ***Applying to the same methods to a two-state paramagnet***

I've tried doing the same thing, but thing are starting to not add up now. Filling in $\Omega=\Omega_\uparrow\Omega_\downarrow$ (multiplicity of a combined system - using a combined system is a guess, but things are not adding up either if I calculate the multiplicity of a single solid), I find:

$$\Omega=\left(\frac{eN}{N_\uparrow}\right)^{N_\uparrow}\left(\frac{eN}{N_\downarrow}\right)^{N_\downarrow}=\frac{\left(eN\right)^{N}}{N_\uparrow^{N_\uparrow}N_\downarrow^{N_\downarrow}}.$$

Filling in $N_\uparrow=N_\downarrow=N/2$, I find:

$$\Omega_\mathrm{max}=\left(2e\right)^N$$

---

Even though I believe this is the wrong answer, the expression itself is not such a big issue until the next exercise, where I'm suppose to calculate the multiplicity function in the vicinity of the peak, by setting $N_\uparrow=\frac{N}{2}+x$ (from which automatically follows $N_\downarrow=\frac{N}{2}-x$).

So far so good, I plug that into the general equation I found for the multiplicity of the combined system. After rewriting a little, I find:

$$\Omega=\left(\frac{eN}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{N}{2}\right)^2-x^2}}\right)^N\left(\frac{N/2-x}{N/2+x}\right)^{x}$$

Apart from being able to plug in $x=0$ which checks out for my previous answer, the result seems very fishy, since I cannot work with it to estimate the height of the peak (third problem - follows now).

---

## ***Calculating the width of the peak in the multiplicity function of combined system of two Einstein solids***

To consider what the graph looks like near the peak, plug in the expressions for up and down-state $N$:

$$\Omega=\left(\frac{e}{N}\right)^{2N}\left[\left(\frac{q}{2}\right)^2-x^2\right]^N$$

Manipulating the logarithm again:

$$\ln\left[\left(\frac{q}{2}\right)^2-x^2\right]^N=N\ln\left[\left(\frac{q}{2}\right)^2-x^2\right]$$

After two steps this check out to be:

$$\ln\left[\left(\frac{q}{2}\right)^2-x^2\right]^N=N\left[\ln\left(\frac{q}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{2x}{q}\right)^2\right]$$

Plugging this back into the original equation for multiplicity, I find $\Omega$ to be:

$$\Omega=\left(\frac{e}{N}\right)^{2N}e^{N\ln(q/2)^2}e^{-N(2x/q)^2}=\Omega_\mathrm{max}\cdot e^{-N(2x/q)^2}.$$

The solution in the text book example is great! It allows to calculate an approximate peak width of $\Delta x=q/\sqrt{N}$ (at which point the multiplicity falls off by a factor of $1/e$). But my equation doesn't check out so nicely with my original expression of $\Omega_\mathrm{max}$, and I'm not sure what next step to take. Any suggestions welcome.

---

## ***EDIT***

Perhaps I wrongly took the low temperature limit for my two-state paramagnet ? Can anyone clarify and explain *why* I should take the high temperature limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I found the answer:

---

First we must determine what value we must set for $N_\uparrow$, given is an expression for $x$, so we rewrite that first to be $N_\uparrow=\frac{N}{2}+x$.

Similarly to the answer to the previous exercise, we now calculate the multiplicity like so:
$$\Omega=\frac{N!}{\left(\frac{N}{2}+x\right)!\left(N-\left(\frac{N}{2}+x\right)\right)!}.
$$
We can rewrite one term a little: $N-\left(N/2+x\right)=N/2-x$, to then take the logarithm on both sides:
$$\ln\Omega=\ln\left(\frac{N!}{\left(\frac{N}{2}+x\right)!\left(N-\left(\frac{N}{2}+x\right)\right)!}\right)$$
        $$=\ln N!-\ln\left(\frac{N}{2}+x\right)!-\ln\left(\frac{N}{2}-x\right)!$$
        $$=\left(N\ln N - N\right)-\left(\left(\frac{N}{2}+x\right)\ln\left(\frac{N}{2}+x\right)-\left(\frac{N}{2}+x\right)\right)-\left(\left(\frac{N}{2}-x\right)\ln\left(\frac{N}{2}-x\right)-\left(\frac{N}{2}-x\right)\right)$$
        $$=N\ln N-\frac{N}{2}\left(\ln\left(\frac{N}{2}-x\right)+\ln\left(\frac{N}{2}+x\right)\right)+x\left(\ln\left(\frac{N}{2}-x\right)-\ln\left(\frac{N}{2}+x\right)\right).$$
Now, we have to manipulate the logarithms in the same fashion as (2.26):

$$\ln\left(\frac{N}{2}+x\right)=\ln\left(\frac{N}{2}\left(1+\frac{2x}{N}\right)\right)$$
                $$=\ln\frac{N}{2}+\ln\left(1+\frac{2x}{N}\right)$$
                $$\approx\ln\frac{N}{2}+\frac{2x}{N}$$
In the same fashion, we find $\ln\left(\frac{N}{2}-x\right)\approx\ln\frac{N}{2}-\frac{2x}{N}$. Substituting this result into equation \ref{eqn:ex2.24.5}:

$$\ln\Omega\approx N\ln N-\frac{N}{2}\left(\left(\ln\frac{N}{2}-\frac{2x}{N}\right)+\left(\ln\frac{N}{2}+\frac{2x}{N}\right)\right)+x\left(\left(\ln\frac{N}{2}-\frac{2x}{N}\right)-\left(\ln\frac{N}{2}+\frac{2x}{N}\right)\right)$$
        $$= N\ln N-\frac{N}{2}\left(2\ln\frac{N}{2}\right)+x\left(-\frac{4x}{N}\right)$$
        $$= N\left(\ln N-\ln\frac{N}{2}\right)-\frac{4x^2}{N}$$
        $$= N\ln2-\frac{4x^2}{N}$$
Similar to equation (2.27), we find the following expression:
$$\Omega=\Omega_\mathrm{max}\cdot e^{-4x^2/N}$$
Filling in $x=0$ shows $\Omega=\Omega_\mathrm{max}$ as desired.

Comment: If you can find a mistake in here, let me know.